# What qualities to look for in wood for a bow drill and why?

Tags: fire-starting

When constructing a bow drill (or hand drill I guess) for the purpose of making fire, which qualities of the wood, or which woods, should I be looking for specifically for different parts?

Obviously it should be as dry as possible...

- But should it be soft wood?
- Hard wood?
- A combination of both?
- Resinous or not?

And importantly *why are these qualities needed*?

(I'm purposefully not asking for specific woods, as you might not know which species to find in various places, but giving common examples would of course be useful.)

Comment: while the question I've linked does ask for species, the accepted answer is more generic, naming species only as examples

Comment: I find the answer in the linked questions somewhat lacking in detail, e.g. why certain qualities are needed.

Comment: Throw a bounty on the question explaining what you'd like to see